# count new users by each months in sql

Tags: mysql, sql

i am trying to count new users recorded by each month of this year.
like

---

Need data month wise, which is registerd by month new users

```
JAn  Feb  Mar  April May ..... Dec

1     2   4     2     5 .....  1
```

through created_at date and user Id.

here is  user_table

```
id     created_at
1      2020-01-09 22:38:55
2      2020-02-09 22:38:55
3      2020-02-09 22:38:55
4      2020-03-09 22:38:55
5      2020-03-09 22:38:55
6      2020-03-09 22:38:55
7      2020-04-09 22:38:55
8      2020-04-09 22:38:55
9      2020-05-09 22:38:55
```

---

i am trying with this query

```
SELECT  ut.id, Month(FROM_UNIXTIME(ut.created_at)), Count(*) 
from  $userTable ut 
where FROM_UNIXTIME(ut.created_at) >= CURDATE() - INTERVAL 1 YEAR
GROUP BY Month(FROM_UNIXTIME(ut.created_at));
```

Comment: See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query

Comment: Firstly you must to count rows grouping by year and month (or specify only one year and group by monts - it is task-dependent). Then you must to pivot this data (it is more useful to perform this on the client side).

Comment: Is `FROM_UNIXTIME()` actually necessary?  Your dates look like they are dates and not numbers.

Answer (score 2):

You can group by year and sum by month like this:

```
 select YEAR(created_at) as year,
  sum(case when Month(created_at) = 1 then 1 else 0 end) AS Jan,
  sum(case when Month(created_at) = 2 then 1 else 0 end) AS Feb,
  sum(case when Month(created_at) = 3 then 1 else 0 end) AS Mar,
  sum(case when Month(created_at) = 4 then 1 else 0 end) AS Apr,
  sum(case when Month(created_at) = 5 then 1 else 0 end) AS May,
  sum(case when Month(created_at) = 6 then 1 else 0 end) AS Jun,
  sum(case when Month(created_at) = 7 then 1 else 0 end) AS Jul,
  sum(case when Month(created_at) = 8 then 1 else 0 end) AS Aug,
  sum(case when Month(created_at) = 9 then 1 else 0 end) AS Sep,
  sum(case when Month(created_at) = 10 then 1 else 0 end) AS Oct,
  sum(case when Month(created_at) = 11 then 1 else 0 end) AS Nov,
  sum(case when Month(created_at) = 12 then 1 else 0 end) AS Dec from ut group by YEAR(created_at)
```

Answer (score 0):

all columns that being used in the select that are not an aggregated function need to be grouped, ut.id is not group and in your case should be removed from the select

Try

```
SELECT  Month(FROM_UNIXTIME(ut.created_at)), Count(*) from  $userTable ut 
where FROM_UNIXTIME(ut.created_at) >= CURDATE() - INTERVAL 1 YEAR
GROUP BY Month(FROM_UNIXTIME(ut.created_at));
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to mix data from this year and last year for the past 12 months, you can use:

```
SELECT SUM(MONTH(FROM_UNIXTIME(ut.created_at)) = 1) AS Jan,
       SUM(MONTH(FROM_UNIXTIME(ut.created_at)) = 2) AS Feb,
       SUM(MONTH(FROM_UNIXTIME(ut.created_at)) = 3) AS Mar,
       SUM(MONTH(FROM_UNIXTIME(ut.created_at)) = 4) AS Apr,
       SUM(MONTH(FROM_UNIXTIME(ut.created_at)) = 5) AS May,
       SUM(MONTH(FROM_UNIXTIME(ut.created_at)) = 6) AS Jun,
       SUM(MONTH(FROM_UNIXTIME(ut.created_at)) = 7) AS Jul,
       SUM(MONTH(FROM_UNIXTIME(ut.created_at)) = 8) AS Aug,
       SUM(MONTH(FROM_UNIXTIME(ut.created_at)) = 9) AS Sep,
       SUM(MONTH(FROM_UNIXTIME(ut.created_at)) = 10) AS Oct,
       SUM(MONTH(FROM_UNIXTIME(ut.created_at)) = 11) AS Nov,
       SUM(MONTH(FROM_UNIXTIME(ut.created_at)) = 12) AS Dec
FROM ut
WHERE FROM_UNIXTIME(ut.created_at) >= CURDATE() - INTERVAL 1 YEAR
```

Note:  This assumes that `FROM_UNIXTIME()` is a actually necessary.  It also uses a convenient MySQL shortcut for conditional aggreation.